# What causes a delay before showing a video?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I have 2 videos. I’m hiding the second video.
I want a new video to play after the first one is completed, without any download.
In theory, after loading it should remain in the cache, but the browser again accesses the directory. However, before playing the second video, a **black screen appears for a split second**.

```js
let myvid = document.getElementById('my-player');
let myvid2 = document.getElementById('my-player2');

myvid.addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
  activeVideo = activeVideo++;

  myvid.src = myvid2.src;

  const playPromise = myvid.play();
  if (playPromise !== null) {
    playPromise.catch(() => {
      myvid.play();
    })
  }
});
```

```css
.second {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<video id="my-player" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" poster="second.mp4" data-setup='{}'>
    <source src="1.MOV" type=" video/mp4"/>
    <p class="vjs-no-js">
        To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a
        web browser that
        <a href="https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">
            supports HTML5 video
        </a>
    </p>
</video>
<section class='second'>
  <video id="my-player2" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" poster="second.mp4" data-setup='{}'>
    <source src="2.MOV" type=" video/mp4"/>
    <p class="vjs-no-js">
        To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a
        web browser that
        <a href="https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">
            supports HTML5 video
        </a>
    </p>
</video>
```

---

How can this black screen be eliminated? If this is not possible, then how could I combine the two videos in JS?

Comment: start it half a second before the end of the first in a hidden <video>. Toggle the visibility when the first video is finish

Comment: It's because of setting the src on myVid.  That's causing it to reload.  What if you just hide myvid and show myVid2 - then play myVid2.

Comment: @Tony Abrams, i  tried to do so. Everything is going well, but on mobile devices this method does not work

Comment: @Below the Radar, I don’t quite understand how to do this, can you show?

Comment: Mobile devices attempt to save bandwidth and will put off anything they can to do so

Comment: Auto-play with audio is not allowed on some browsers (mobile Safari, Chrome, Firefox?). On some browsers, you can mute the player to allow autoplay, while some (Safari, iirc) does not allow autoplay unless user interaction was made (i.e. the user explicitly played the video). I don't remember which ones do which, you can look this up.

Comment: That is, on mobile devices it will not work out the way I want? maybe then there is a way to combine these 2 videos?

Comment: Instead of using the ended event to start the video, use a timeout with the length of the first video inside the started event

Comment: @Below the Radar, I tried it, it got better. But the "blinking" still remains. Maybe i can remove it?

Comment: maybe use z-index instead of display to toggle the videos

Comment: @Below the Radar, At this moment, should I completely hide the video player?

Comment: I dont know, try hiding with z-index switch or just z-index switch

Comment: Hey! I noticed you got a lot of comments trying to help you. I hope you could figure something out. If you did, please do post an answer to your own question! It's a very good way of sharing your solutions with the community, and you can accept it as well =)